Prove that 8x≡4 mod16 is solvable or not in ℤ
So, I approached this by rewriting it as (4 - 8x)/16, which is equal to (1-2x)/4. Every number multiplied by 2 gives us an even number and every equal number +/-1 is equal to an odd number, which therefore can't be divisble by 4. Can you give me a better solution than that, because it seems too wordy, there has to be a more elegant way to prove it for sure.
There is a second problem, which is 8x ≡ 4 mod 15.

Multiply both sides by 2

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Hint. If $a \equiv b \bmod 16$, then $a \equiv b \bmod 8$.
